# Visual Studio 2019 - C# Windows Forms Designer- Not able to add items from the toolbox

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2019, windows-forms-designer

The issue is explained quite simple.. everytime when I try to add an item from the toolbox there is the error message: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

I choose an item.. e.g. a button and drag and drop it to the form.. after releasing the button the error message with the object reference appears.. everytime..

After the message the item is visible in the form. I would like to fix this issue.
I am using the community version with .NET Framework 4.7.2

[image]

Comment: Have you tried to [Repair Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/repair-visual-studio?view=vs-2019)?

Comment: If not running the latest version, you may try upgrading.

Comment: I have repaired VS and after that upgraded to the current version and now it works. Thanks a lot for the quick advice!